# Return list of common email ids from a list of lists

Tags: java, algorithm

Input: ArrayList of ArrayLists with email ids.
Output: Return ArrayList of email ids which appears in each inner ArrayList.

Ex: Input: [[abc@gmail.com, bca@gmail.com],[abc@gmail.com,bca@gmail.com,bca@gmail.com],[abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com]]
Output: [abc@gmail.com]

I have written the code using `HashSet` and `HashMap` and could get the required output but I'm not sure how optimized and efficient my method is.

```
public static List<String> Common(List<List<String>> email1){

        List<String> res= new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        Set<String> set ;
        int cou = 0;
        for( List list : email1)
        {
            set = new HashSet<String>();
            List<String> temp = list;
            for(String i: temp){
                if(!set.contains(i)){
                    if(map.get(i) !=null){
                        map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
                    }else{
                        map.put(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            cou++;
        }

        int size = email1.size();

        for(String count: map.keySet()){
            if(map.get(count)== size)
            {
                System.out.println(count);
                res.add(count); 
            }
        }

        return res; // << this 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `HashSet` is fine, but you don't need to keep the count of occurrence of each email, you can just keep in the `HashSet` those that appear in all list, and remove all other emails.

```
//Need to check if email1 is empty before this step!
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(); 
set.addAll(email1.get(0));
for(int i = 1; i < email1.size(); i++){
    HashSet<String> tmp = new HashSet();
    for(String email : email1.get(i)){
        if(set.contains(email)){//If set contains this email, keep it!
           tmp.add(email);
        }
    }
    set = tmp;//Important step
}
//All emails will be in the set
System.out.println(set);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Collections.retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) can act as an intersection operator.

Note that your method can be more liberal in the types that it accepts, if you use generics effectively.

```
public static <T> List<T> commonList(Collection<? extends List<T>> collectionOfLists) {
    if (collectionOfLists.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    Iterator<? extends List<T>> iter = collectionOfLists.iterator();
    List<T> first = new ArrayList<T>(iter.next());
    Set<T> common = new HashSet<T>(first);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        common.retainAll(iter.next());
    }
    first.retainAll(common);
    return first;
}
```

Assuming that the order of the resulting entries doesn't matter (I don't see why it should), you should return a `Set` instead of a `List`.

```
public static <T> Set<T> commonSet(Collection<? extends Collection<T>> collectionOfCollections) {
    if (collectionOfCollections.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    Iterator<? extends Collection<T>> iter = collectionOfCollections.iterator();
    Set<T> common = new HashSet<T>(iter.next());
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        common.retainAll(iter.next());
    }
    return common;
}
```

By the Single Responsibility Principle, I don't recommend polluting this function that computes the intersection with `System.out.println()` calls.  Keep the printing in a separate method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer using `retainAll` from the Set interface:

```
public static List<String> commonEmails(List<List<String>> emailLists) {
    if (emailLists.size() > 0) {
        Set<String> commonEmails = new HashSet<String>(emailLists.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < emailLists.size(); i++) {
            commonEmails.retainAll(emailLists.get(i));
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(commonEmails);
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```